# How to derive a base class with a class that only has a constructor with parameters when the base class doesn't specify a constructor?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I have a base class(lets call it BaseClass) which is never instantiated(is this called a virtual base class?). Another class(lets call UsingClass) uses it so it can take different derived classes(DerivedClassN) as inputs.  Since I  never explicitly instantiate this base class I don't define a constructor for it.  The derived class has a constructor that takes types that the base class doesn't know about so its not overriding any constructor.  I want to know the proper way to write the constructors for the two classes.

Right now in BaseClass I declare public variables and virtual functions used in UsingClass and In DerivedClass0 I override those functions, define those variables and declare and define the Constructor which takes parameters.  But I get the following errors:

```
undefined reference to `typeinfo for BaseClass'

undefined reference to `vtable for BaseClass'
test.o: In function `DerivedClass::~DerivedClass()'
```

I understand this is because I never wrote the constructor for the BaseClass or overwrote the parameterless default constructor.  But it doesn't make sense for me to do so.  The parameters for the constructor of DerivedClass take are to complex to just instantiate in a parameterless constructor and the BaseClass doesn't know about the parameters for the Derived class to declare a constructor in the BaseClass to be overwritten. So I'm wondering what I should.  Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

*Actual* Code:

```
class BaseClass {
public:
    virtual ~BaseClass();
    virtual double  get(int the_params);
    virtual void    set(int he_params);
    int   _a_local;
};

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {
    private:
        int _priveate_variables;
        void private_function();
    public:
        explicit DerivedClass(int the_int);
        virtual double  get(int the_int);
        virtual void    set(int the_int);
};

DerivedClass::DerivedClass(int the_int) : _priveate_variables(the_int) {
    _priveate_variables++;
    _a_local=_priveate_variables;
}


double DerivedClass::get(int the_int) {
     return 0.0;
}

void DerivedClass::set(int the_int) {
     _priveate_variables = 2;

}
```

**Errors**

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/5.3.0/../../../../lib/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
/tmp/ccC1wbix.o: In function `BaseClass::BaseClass()':
CodeForThem.cc:(.text._ZN9BaseClassC2Ev[_ZN9BaseClassC5Ev]+0x9): undefined reference to `vtable for BaseClass'
/tmp/ccC1wbix.o: In function `DerivedClass::~DerivedClass()':
CodeForThem.cc:(.text._ZN12DerivedClassD2Ev[_ZN12DerivedClassD5Ev]+0x20): undefined reference to `BaseClass::~BaseClass()'
/tmp/ccC1wbix.o:(.rodata._ZTI12DerivedClass[_ZTI12DerivedClass]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for BaseClass'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Did you define `virtual Base::~Base() {}`?

Comment: Please show the *actual* code, not a long *description* of the code.

Comment: Yes I have the virtual destructor.  Sorry about not being specific.  I also added actual code that we can work with.  Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't your `BaseClass` virtual destructor, virtual function `get`, and virtual function `set` at least define a body (even if it is `{}`)? Or if `get` and `set` are suppose to be pure virtual functions, they should be defined with `= 0` after them?

Comment: @Michael: thanks that is it.   do you mean the assignment operator "=" ?

Comment: No I mean `= 0` on a function declaration that can define them as pure virtual functions. Like `virtual double  get(int the_params) = 0;` . This would force a derived class to provide a function `get` function or it would throw a compile time error.

Comment: O cool, that's cleaner then the empty body.  Can I do that for the destructor too?

Comment: No, not on a virtual destructor. You need to provide a body (even if it does nothing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to write a constructor for `BaseClass`, it will be given a "default constructor" (and copy-constructor) anyway.  This compiler-generated default constructor will be called by the `DerivedClass` constructor automatically.

As for your linking error, that's probably because you failed to define the virtual destructor for your `BaseClass`.  You need to define it with an empty body even if it is pure-virtual (it should be `virtual`, whether it is pure (`=0`) or not is immaterial).

Comment: "Failed to define" is a bit strong. The code is valid; the compiler is wrong. Adding a destructor is the well-known workaround.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Are you saying that most compilers in use today have a bug when they reject code which tries to instantiate a base class which has a pure virtual destructor with no definition?  That would be truly shocking, and would go against accepted wisdom on this site and many others.  The internet consensus seems to be that C++ actually requires defining a pure virtual destructor.  Are you saying we've all got it wrong?

Comment: The error messages aren't about a missing definition of a destructor. They say that the linker can't find the vtable and typeinfo information that are mentioned in the object code generated for the (presumably compiler-generated) destructor of `DerivedClass`. There's nothing in the question to indicate that the base class is defined to have a pure virtual destructor.

Comment: @John Zwinck Thanks for the comments guys.  They are all very informative.  I saw the problem with the vitrual destructor and checked for that but my problem is else where.

Comment: @Shane: OK, so your problem is in fact that you are not defining `~BaseClass()`.  You are declaring it only.  You need to define it, even if it's empty.

Comment: And I should also do the same for all other virtual functions?  Is there a good reason the compiler requires adding these declarations?

Comment: Please read about "pure virtual functions".  Apart from the destructor, you can make the other `BaseClass` functions pure virtual to avoid needed to define them.